# Find and remove/merge all duplicate parties in MS Dynamics AX 2012 R2 global address book

Tags: duplicates, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there a way to find all duplicate parties in MS Dynamics AX 2012 R2 global address book (GAB) and then remove/merge them?

I know that in GAB there is a "Check for duplicates" option, but it works only for the currently selected one party item. However, I need to search within all records and find duplicates against some criteria.

In MS CRM there is a built-in duplicate detection and merge mechanism and I'm wondering why such is not found in Dynamics AX... or I am wrong?

Nevertheless, besides direct-database-manipulation mechanism, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do some development for something custom. The form `\Forms\DirPartyCheckDuplicate` is designed for a single party.

You can use the backing class `\Classes\DirPartyCheckDuplicate` to do the searches and then handle the results using some custom form.

The issue is that the class is also designed to accept a `DirPartyTable` record, then return a `query` of duplicates.

If you want to search everywhere to just *identify* things that have duplicates, you could hack something together.  I wrote this quick job where I have 2 DirPartyTable records that return duplicates and I ran the check twice and combined the results and output them.

```
static void Job3(Args _args)
{
    DirPartyTable       dpt = DirPartyTable::findRec(22565431216);
    DirPartyTable       dpt2 = DirPartyTable::findRec(22565424587);
    Query               targetQuery;
    Query               otherQuery;
    QueryRun            qr;
    DirPartyTable       dirPartyTable;

    DirPartyCheckDuplicate partyCheckDuplicate;

    partyCheckDuplicate = DirPartyCheckDuplicate::construct();
    partyCheckDuplicate.parmPartyRecord(dpt);
    partyCheckDuplicate.parmCheckName(true);
    partyCheckDuplicate.run();
    targetQuery = partyCheckDuplicate.getQuery();

    partyCheckDuplicate = DirPartyCheckDuplicate::construct();
    partyCheckDuplicate.parmPartyRecord(dpt2);
    partyCheckDuplicate.parmCheckName(true);
    partyCheckDuplicate.run();
    otherQuery = partyCheckDuplicate.getQuery();

    SysQuery::mergeRanges(targetQuery, otherQuery);

    qr = new QueryRun(targetQuery);

    while (qr.next())
    {
        dirPartyTable = qr.get(tableNum(DirPartyTable));

        info(DirPartyTable.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is a great idea. However, I don't want to just identify, but also to remove duplicates (I will fix that in my question). Is this still possible with these custom made jobs? I will have to do a vast research on these. Should I expect any performance issues for scanning 10000 records, checking duplicates for each, combining 10000 queries and finally displaying the result of the expected 30% duplicate records? What do you think? Is your approach still relevant, or should I search for another one?

Comment: What you want to do is a complex task and it should be developed from scratch based on the logic found in `DirPartyCheckDuplicate` class. There could be some performance issues, but as it's likely a one time operation, it shouldn't matter. You could/should also develop some history table to review removals, do it in Dev/Test first, etc.